# Why do I need the aspectjtools dependency even if I do not use AspectJ annotations in a Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have the following beans.xml

```
<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="bar" class="biz.tugay.spashe.aspect.BarImpl"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="bar">
        <aop:before method="bar"
                    pointcut="target(biz.tugay.spashe.Foo))"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

<!-- Business Logic -->
<bean id="foo" class="biz.tugay.spashe.FooImpl"/>
```

And as you see I am **not** using the element:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

which is used to enabling AspectJ support in Spring Framework according to the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-enable-aspectj-xml).

And the aspect I have, `BarImpl` is a POJO:

```
public class BarImpl {

    public void bar() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Before..");
    }
}
```

and I expect this project to compile and run just fine. However, in runtime I am getting the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5c7b24c2': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#24ee8489' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#24ee8489': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
```

which is only fixed if I add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.12</version>
</dependency>
```

to my project.

Why do I need the **aspectjtools** dependency in this situation? And how can I configure Spring Framework for Aspect Oriented programming without AspectJ support?

Comment: Because that's where most of the AspectJ tools live. Native Spring AOP it's covered in their docs, although I don't actually know what's available in the last several releases.

Comment: What do you think `pointcut="target(biz.tugay.spashe.Foo))` is, that is an AspectJ pointcut expression and for that AspectJ is needed to parse it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is there any other way to declare pointcuts in Spring Framework? If not, can we say that Spring AOP not supports AspectJ, but rather depends on AspectJ?

Comment: I suggest a read of the manual, you could also use a regexp or ant-style expression but those are rather limited. Also to parse the AspectJ expressions in XML it has a dependency on AspectJ but it also supports the  `@Aspect` way of writing aspects (which is basically the supports part). It isn't one or the other it depends on your usage.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am trying to read the manuals but can not find anywhere pointcuts defined with anything but AspectJ pointcut expressions. (or without AspectJ weaever dependency..)

Comment: You would need to define an `advisor` instead of an `aspect` and do a bit more manual configuration.